# How to get EXIF data of post images in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, metadata, exif

I understand that the EXIF data extracted from uploaded images are stored in the WordPress database, but i am not finding the proper way to find them or get them in a post for instance. I was looking around on web but all solutions found didn't work.

Do you know an efficient way to get the EXIF data of a picture from post? I don't mind if is a php or jQuery solution as long it does the job.

Thanks for your time.

LATER EDIT: actually i found the reason for my problem. I managed to call the wp_get_attachment_metadata but except the width and height of image, i receive zero for camera, aperture, ISO, focal lenght, shutter speed etc. The call is something like $imgmeta['image_meta']['camera']

is there something i am missing?

LATER LATER EDIT: Found the issue. server extension php_exif wasn't enabled. thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [EXIF Read Data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) from php.net. Folow first example and you should be able to extract whatever you want ...

EDIT: or you can use [jQuery EXIF](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exifjquery/)
EDIT 2: for jQuery you must use same domain as the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) applies to EXIF reader as it uses HTTP Requests

Comment: thanks. i know about this php function but i am not a php master, so what is there isn't helping me too much. that example is ok for a website with static path, but not sure how i can use it in wordpress for dinamic pulling thumbnails functions (like <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'my-thumbnail' ); ?> ), images etc. i am looking more about already integrated solutions or wordpress examples. thanks.

Comment: that's ambiguous because not all users use same image upload system. Basically you can get the file location and run the ``exif_read_data`` directly into the post ...

Comment: for wordpress i mean the standard media upload option.

Comment: yes, i know also about that jquery plugin. i used but with no luck. it show nothing even was proper installed.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the wordpress plugin "[HK EXIF tags](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hk-exif-tags/)", which just adds one line below each image with the EXIF information.

Comment: OP wasn't looking for a plugin. You don't happen to be affiliated with this one, do you?